# Invalid reference from destroy provisioner after TF upgrade

Tags: azure, terraform

I keep getting an error when trying tf apply:

```
Destroy-time provisioners and their connection configurations may only reference attributes of the related resource, via 'self', 'count.index', or 'each.key'.

References to other resources during the destroy phase can cause dependency cycles and interact poorly with create_before_destroy.
```

Below is my code any idea why this is happening?

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pip" {
  count = (var.enable_public_ip) && lower(local.is_linux_validation) || lower(local.is_windows_validation) ? 1 : 0
  name  = "${var.vm_name}-public-ip"
  location = data.azurerm_resource_group.vm_rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.vm_rg.name
  allocation_method   = var.public_ip_allocation_method
  tags  = var.tags
  
  # Deassociate Public IP from NIC before destroying it
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when = destroy
    command = "az network nic ip-config update --name ${var.vm_name}-ip --resource-group ${data.azurerm_resource_group.vm_rg.name} --nic-name ${var.vm_name}-nic --remove PublicIpAddress"
    on_failure = continue
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `data` source. Try replacing it with `self.resource_group_name`.

Comment: you mean for the location and  resource_group_name?

Comment: I meant to replace data source in the `command` of the `local-exec` provisioner.

Comment: Ah ok so where it says " --resource-group ${data.azurerm_resource_group.vm_rg.name}"  replace with  --resource-group ${self.resource_group_name}? thank you

Comment: Yup, not sure that will work though. :)

Comment: Yeah that didnt work still getting "Error: Invalid reference from destroy provisioner"

Comment: Ok, now let's get back to the start: what is the reason for doing this? Can it not get removed when the resource for NIC is destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

Because Terraform visits dependencies in reverse order when destroying (so that a child will be destroyed before its parent, for example), by the time Terraform is running destroy-time provisioners all of the other objects that the resource depends on have already been destroyed, and so it isn't valid to refer to them.

As the error message says, the configuration for a `when = destroy` provisioner may refer only to `self` (the current instance being destroyed), `count.index` (the index of the current instance being destroyed), or `each.key` (the `for_each` key of the current instance being destroyed).

Your provisioner configuration refers to two other objects which are not valid to use here:

- `var.vm_name`
- `data.azurerm_resource_group.vm_rg.name`

To proceed you will need to find alternative ways to get this same information by reference to `self`.

For `data.azurerm_resource_group.vm_rg.name` it seems like you assigned exactly the same value to this resource's own `resource_group_name` argument, and so `self.resource_group_name` would be a drop-in replacement.

You haven't use `var.vm_name` alone as any of the arguments of this resource, so deriving `${var.vm_name}-ip` and `${var.vm_name}-nic` will require some more ingenuity. It seems like it should be possible to derive them both from `self.name` though, since it shares the common prefix:

- `${trimsuffix(self.name, "-public-ip")}-ip`
- `${trimsuffix(self.name, "-public-ip")}-nic`

This relies on the fact that these two arguments share a common prefix with `self.name`, and thus you can trim off the extra suffix and then append a different one to calculate the name of the corresponding "ip" and "nic".

---

In Terraform, [provisioners are a last resort](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#provisioners-are-a-last-resort) and so if at all possible it would be better to manage this association between the public IP and its NIC using a Terraform `resource` block. If the Azure provider doesn't offer a mechanism to do that then it may be worth opening a feature request in the provider's repository to discuss it, so that in future you could hopefully switch to a resource-based approach where Terraform will be able to manage these relationships properly and thus avoid this trickery with reverse-engineering object names.

Comment: Hi Martine thanks for this! for the "self.resource_group_name" where do i need to replace this? is it in "resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.vm_rg.name" or in the command line: "--resource-group ${data.azurerm_resource_group.vm_rg.name}"?

Comment: The references inside the `provisioner "local-exec"` block are what are causing the problem, so those are the ones you need to replace with references to attributes of `self`.